# How to remove xmlns="" from xml request

Tags: java, xml, soap, namespaces, axis

i'm trying to remove blank xmlns from the xml request generated from stub that i've auto-generated from a wsdl using the axis wizard.

Axis wizard generates the request class in which there is:

```
 private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(Request.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://myNamespace"));
        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("destinationIdsInfo");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "DestinationIdsInfo"));//IF I REMOVE THIS EVERY ELEMENT INSIDE THAT TAG WILL HAVE xmlns="".
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "DestinationIdInfo"));
        elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        elemField.setItemQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "DestinationIdInfo"));
        ....
   }
```

This generates me an xml like this:

```
...
<DestinationIdsInfo xmlns="">
    <DestinationIdInfo id="xxxx"/>
</DestinationIdsInfo>
...
```

But i need

```
<DestinationIdsInfo>
    <DestinationIdInfo id="xxxx"/>
</DestinationIdsInfo>
```

How can i solve??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the same namespace URI for your nested elements:

```
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://myNamespace", 
                                                   "DestinationIdsInfo"))
```

(Ditto for `DestinationIdInfo`.)

It will then inherit the namespace from the containing element, which is why I believe you want.

See the [XML namespaces specification section 6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#defaulting) for more information about namespace defaulting.

Comment: if i specify namespace URI it will appear in my xml request and i don't need it (web service's owners don't want that namespace in the request)

Comment: @JackTurky: No, it shouldn't - because you're already *inheriting* that namespace from one of the enclosing elements. Look for an `xmlns="http://myNamespace"` element in one of the enclosing elements in your XML. If you don't want any namespaces *anywhere*, you should get rid of all of them.

Comment: You know that you are the best? :) My problem was that axis generates me classes with different namespace, so the only thing i do is to uniform namespace everywhere and now all element of xml inherit namespace from root element :) Thank youuu!!!!!!!!!