# How to remove an specific xml attribute from org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this XML:

```
<Body xmlns:wsu="http://mynamespace">           
 <Ticket xmlns="http://othernamespace">
  <Customer xlmns="">Robert</Customer>
  <Products xmlns="">
   <Product>a product</>
  </Products>               
 </Ticket>
 <Delivered xmlns="" />
 <Payment xlmns="">cash</Payment>
</Body>
```

I am using Java to read it as a DOM document.  I want remove the empty namespace attributes (i.e., `xmlns=""`).  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is that the whole document or just a fragment?  If it's the whole document then the serializer shouldn't have added `xmlns=""` to the `Delivered` and `Payment` elements as they have no inherited default namespace to override.

Comment: It is a fragment. A header part with ws-security its on top. That xml its a WS request generater by axis. I don`t know why axis put thats empty namespaces there.

Comment: If you have a DOM element that is not in a namespace and you try to add it to a tree that has a default namespace in force then the XML serializer has no choice - it _must_ add `xmlns=""` in order to accurately output the XML you've given it.  If you don't want the `xmlns=""` then you must ensure that the element is created with the same namespace as the default that is in force at the place where the element is to be inserted.

Comment: You can't "remove" namespace declarations, the serializer will automatically create whatever declarations are required to match the namespaces the nodes are in.  If the namespaces are right, the declarations will automatically be right too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that `xmlns` is a *very special* attribute. Basically, the `xmlns=""` is so that your `Customer` element is in the "unnamed" namespace, rather than the `http://othernamespace` namespace (and likewise for other elements which would otherwise inherit a default namespace from their ancestors).

If you want to get rid of the `xmlns=""`, you basically need to put the elements into the appropriate namespace - so it's changing the element name. I don't *think* the W3C API lets you change the name of an element - you may well need to create a new element with the appropriate namespaced-name, and copy the content. Or if you're responsible for creating the document to start with, just use the right namespace.

Comment: Thanks! But now my question is: if I remove the Customer namespace which is empty (on this case xmlns="") wouldn't I be referencing the top namespace by default? i.e. "http ://othernamespace" on this case

Comment: @user1750751: Yes, you would. Basically, you need to work out which namespace the `Customer` element *should* be in - if you want it in the empty namespace, then leave the `xmlns=""`. If you want it in `http://othernamespace`, take it out. Alternatively, change the *parent* element to something like: `<other:Ticket xmlns:other="http://othernamespace">` which then wouldn't set a default.

Comment: Jon, I have this same problem that you answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004734/how-to-remove-xmlns-from-xml-request

Comment: @user1750751: Well that's using Axis... it's not really clear what your context is, to be honest.

Comment: Axis generate that xml. But I have "elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http ://othernamespace/", "customer"));" so, I want to remove "manualy" (by code)

Comment: It's still not clear where that code is, or what you're doing. I strongly suggest you edit the question to give more details - ideally with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.